# Is there a way to find index of "in" keyword match in python

Tags: python

The title of this post is probably pretty vague. Here is what I need to know

If I use something like

```
if x in list
```

how do I find the index in the list where a match occurs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get that from `in` itself.  For lists, you can use the `index` method:

```
>>> [1, 2, 5, 8, -1, 2].index(2)
1
```

This will raise an exception if the item is not in the list.  Note that it returns the index of the *first* occurrence.  It might occur multiple times.

Comment: thanks! The first occurrence is good enough for the program I'm writing since the list elements are unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

It's better to use `list_.index(x)` for this use case.

If there's a match in your sequence zero or multiple times, you should prefer to use `enumerate`:

```
>>> list_ = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'foo', 'eggs']
>>> idxs = [i for i,x in enumerate(list_) if x == 'foo']
>>> print idxs
[0, 3]
```